# Performing spatial logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic, spatial, gis, spatial-interaction-model

I am trying to perform a logistic regression with the following code

> `Y ~ x1+x2+x3,data=data, family=binomial(link="logit")`.

However on inspection of both the outcome and predictors i noticed that they are characterized by spatial auto-correlation. My question is, how do I account for the spatial auto-correlation, to get better coefficients?

Comment: You should'nt call your data 'data', you wouldn't call your dog 'dog', would you? (sorry, shamelessly borrowed from an old S-help posting)

Comment: There is a CRAN package `geoRglm`, try that?

Comment: @kjetil If `R` did not generously recognize that the use of `data` here cannot possibly reference the built-in `data` function, there would be a problem.  If, in order to write working code, people had to memorize the names of all objects in the base `R` environment so as to avoid re-using them, nobody would be using `R` today.  So: in a program that utilizes just one dataset, just as in a world where there is only one dog, there seems to be no problem calling the dataset `data` or the dog "dog". Indeed, in doing so there's some relief from the need to invent yet another name.

Comment: The suggestion by @kjetil is a good one.  However, since your predictors are spatially correlated, one of the first things to do is assess whether the *residuals* of your regression exhibit any important spatial correlation.  If they do not, maybe you don't have to worry about this issue.